# Run two shell scripts in parallel then run another one after both finished

Tags: linux, shell

I have 3 shell scripts, I need to run the first two in parallel then run the third one after both (first two) scripts finished. How do I do this? All I know is running the first two scripts in background.

```
sh script1.sh &
sh script2.sh &
sh script3.sh &
```

I believe the third script will still continue with this one.

How would the third script 'wait' for them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`wait`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html) builtin. It should be:

```
sh script1.sh &
sh script2.sh &
wait
sh script3.sh
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Will do this one! I thought the wait function should have pid

Answer (score 0):

[GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) is a tool to execute commands in parallel:

```
parallel -j2 ::: './script1.sh' './script1.sh' && ./script3.sh
```

Both *script1* and *script2* will be executed in parallel and after both are finished *script3* will be executed.

[Parallel's tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html) shows more advanced behavior customization, in case it is needed

Comment: Depending on the exit status of `script1` and `script2`, `script3` may not run. I would replace the `&& ./script3.sh` by `; ./script3.sh`.